# how to use jmeter to update xml to post later

Tags: jmeter

I have a JMeter job that I'm taking the XML response from, updating the XML, then PUT the XML back to update the record. I have ALL the parts, except the XML update part.

I need to update XML root/Settings/HasRetry from not only "false" to "true", but also add other nodes directly under it.  Order matters in this XML.

[xml to update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKzVQ.png)

Ideas on the best way to do this?  I tried a via a simple java script:

[java replace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUtd1.png)

...but the JS pukes on that b/c of the special characters in the XML string.

Ideas?

Comment: and yes I know it's sloppy to do a string replace, BUT that was a simpler way to keep the nodes in order

Comment: did you write that script on JavaScript? Not going to work. E.g. `var str = '${myVar}';` will fail, you need to say `String str = vars.get("myVar");` (it should be written in Java). If you want to write JavaScript, use JSR223 Sampler and choose javascript as a language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error in your script, last line should look like `vars.put("ResponceData", res);` as your current implementation simply ignores the replacement logic.

Also be aware that [it is not recommended to use Beanshell for scripting](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting), since JMeter 3.1 users are encouraged to switch to [JSR223 Test Elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and [Groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) language.

Groovy is Java compliant hence in majority of cases valid Beanshell code will be a valid Groovy code, however it is not recommended to use JMeter Variables references like `${ResponceData}` as it will ruin scripts compilation feature and performance will be a big question mark so switch to `vars.get('ResponceData')` instead.

Example Groovy code for values replacement will look something like:

```
def str = vars.get('ResponceData')        
def res = str.replace(vars.get('findSearch'), vars.get('findReplaceWith'))
vars.put('ResponceData', res)
```

Demo:

[image: Groovy String Replace]

See [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) to learn more about Groovy scripting in JMeter.